# Jenkins and SVN timeout

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm having nightmare with proper setup of Jenkins and automatic commits, here's some background:

- SVN 1.6.5 is on Apache 2.2.12 (Ubuntu 12)
- Jenkins is in version 1.551 (RHEL 6.5)

Problem: last Friday server with Jenkins had rebooted (Xen related issue) and since then DNS gone wrong (they went missing), so what I did, I restored DNS servers to resolv.conf and then restarted Jenkins etc. And since then I'm getting random (like 3 of 5 try are failing, 2 are fine) failed commits to SVN (job logs) like:

- svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
- svn: E175002: Connection timed out 
  this or connection reset sometimes.

Manual commits from server with Jenkins are going fine and take like few seconds. I tried to increase Timeout value in Apache, checked logs etc. but nothing special. Just SVN errors like above. What else possibly could go wrong? Firewall etc is not an issue, SVN server is up and running unchanged for long time. I have no idea where to look for clues :(

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, though there were correct rules in iptables, svn worked randomly, however after turning off iptables for good, there are no more errors with timeout! How iptables can work once and other time not? I don't know...